# adding html in image directory

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

can someone help me how do I add html code to a directory that has images?

Actually what I want is to monetize my site properly by adding adds in URLs like this-
http://foodwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/choc-80001-833x1024.jpg

Suppose this is the directory- http://foodwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/
Can I just add html code in 1 file having my adds to be displayed, and then being called everytime when similar images are accessed?

May be using htaccess?

Thanks

Comment: You're wanting image requests to redirect to HTML pages containing the image requested and an ad? There are a number of reasons that won't work well/isn't a good idea.

Comment: Don't use hacks to turn your images into html. Set up a proper gallery system.

Comment: i just want to add adds to that directory having only images, don't know how or if can be done through htaccess

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use url rewriting to pass the requested image to a php script that displays your page... something similar to this may work:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /path/to/images/.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /image_handler.php/$0 [PT]
```

Then you would obviously need the php script to display your page content and image

You can find out more about url rewriting here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html